# Backward compatibility of R code

Tags: r, release-management

I am not a R user but I am preparing for an upgrade of R from 3.0.2 to 3.3.1 on a multi users platform.
I red that in general some packages are not backward compatible with some warnings beetween version releases about deprecated functions.
But my question is more "global" : can you run a code written with R 3.0 on R 3.3 without changing any lines ?
If no, is it a big change or minor evolvment required on the code ?

Edit : Do you know most common embedded packages (source from cran r project) which need changes in the code ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possibly, or possibly not. It depends on the code. Some code will run perfectly without modification, others will need changes.

Comment: R-core avoids almost all breaking changes, so old base R (and even S) should mostly run without incident. Individual packages can deprecate or remove functions, though. Error/warning messages will normally tell you what should be updated.

Comment: Tks both of you, i am editing the original post to add a question.

Comment: I'm not sure about your edited question, but you can checkout the `checkpoint` package - written by Microsoft - to use packages as they were at a certain snapshot date.

Comment: Thanks Zach for your comment. I heard about it. It can be an option with several libpath depending on needs. Also rstudio pro server allow multiple version of R. And last, anaconda for R with a "backward" irkernel.

Answer (score 2):

Note that R packages usually are not tightly coupled to the R version; most likely you could compile your existing version of packages on 3.3 if you needed to (such as if you discover one of your users can't upgrade).

I have rarely had major issues with R package upgrades; you might be OK warning your users about the upgrade and then just helping them reactively if they need it.

One popular package which has recently had non-backwards-compatible changes is ggplot: the qplot() function has had many features removed in version 2.0 and some applications must now be written with ggplot() instead.  If you are going to upgrade ggplot from a version older than 2.0 to newer than 2.0, I would expect some trouble around that.